# Array of hashes manipulation

Tags: perl, perl-module, perl-data-structures

I'm running the script below to query a monitoring system and the results I get back are in array of hashes. What is the best way to access the individual hashes and their elements?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use YMS::Client::MonStatus;
use Getopt::Long;
use DBI::Dumper;
use Data::Dumper;
use YMS::Client::MonStatus::Filter;

my $username = "username";
my $password = "passwd";
my $cluster  = "aso";

#my $filter = YMS::Client::MonStatus::Filter();
my $client  = YMS::Client::MonStatus->new($cluster);
$client->verbose("on");
$client->byauth({username => $username, password => "$password"});
$client->yms_rotation("bot.ops.com:4080");
$client->debug("on");

my $filter = YMS::Client::MonStatus::Filter->new();
$filter->add("cluster", "=", "aso");
$filter->add("host", "in", "<hostname>");
#$filter->add("service", "=", "Prod-Deploy");
$filter->add("status", "=", "OK");
my %args = (
    "filters" => $filter,
    "times"   => {
        "start" => "now - 4 hours",
        "end"   => "now"
    },
);
$client->filters($filter);
#$client->saved_list();
$client->status_list(\%args);

my @result = $client->output;
my $field  = scalar (@result);

#print Dumper (@result);
#my $ref = $result[0][0]->[0];
#print Dumper ($result[0][0]);

print $field;
for ( my $i = 0; $i < $field; $i++ ) {
    print $result[$i]{'notification_enabled'} ."\n";
}
```

The output I get querying the API is as below.

```
$VAR1 = [
                      {
                        'acknowledged' => 'N/A',
                        'check_type' => 'ACTIVE',
                        'current_attempt' => 1,
                        'deleted' => 0,
                        'dimensions' => {
                                          'cluster' => '<cluster>',
                                          'service' => '<servicename>',
                                          'host' => 'hostfoobaar'
                                        },
                        'flapping' => 'N/A',
                        'frequency' => 0,
                        'hidden' => 0,
                        'last_ack_time' => 0,
                        'last_check_time' => 1432875229,
                        'last_comment_time' => 0,
                        'last_delete_time' => 1432875229,
                        'last_downtime_time' => 0,
                        'last_notif_time' => 0,
                        'last_state_change' => 1432875094,
                        'last_status_change' => 1432875094,
                        'max_attempt' => 1,
                        'msg_length' => 10,
                        'notification_enabled' => 'ENABLED',
                        'num_comments' => 0,
                        'quality_metric' => 0,
                        's_0' => 0,
                        's_1' => 0,
                        's_2' => 0,
                        's_3' => 0,
                        's_4' => 0,
                        's_5' => 0,
                        's_6' => 0,
                        's_7' => 0,
                        's_8' => 0,
                        's_9' => 0,
                        'scheduled_downtime' => 'NO',
                        'source' => '',
                        'state' => 'HARD',
                        'status' => 'OK',
                        'status_msg' => 'status ok',
                        'trap' => 1,
                        'ts_0' => 1432875229,
                        'ts_1' => 1432875094,
                        'ts_2' => 0,
                        'ts_3' => 0,
                        'ts_4' => 0,
                        'ts_5' => 0,
                        'ts_6' => 0,
                        'ts_7' => 0,
                        'ts_8' => 0,
                        'ts_9' => 0
                      }
                    ];`
```

Here's the output of print Dumper \@results

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            {
              'acknowledged' => 'N/A',
              'check_type' => 'ACTIVE',
              'current_attempt' => 1,
              'deleted' => 0,
              'dimensions' => {
                                'cluster' => 'aso',
                                'service' => 'system_launch',
                                'host' => 'hostfoobar'
                              },
              'flapping' => 'N/A',
              'frequency' => 0,
              'hidden' => 0,
              'last_ack_time' => 0,
              'last_check_time' => 1432875317,
              'last_comment_time' => 0,
              'last_delete_time' => 0,
              'last_downtime_time' => 0,
              'last_notif_time' => 0,
              'last_state_change' => 1432875317,
              'last_status_change' => 1432875317,
              'max_attempt' => 1,
              'msg_length' => 10,
              'notification_enabled' => 'ENABLED',
              'num_comments' => 0,
              'quality_metric' => 0,
              's_0' => 0,
              's_1' => 0,
              's_2' => 0,
              's_3' => 0,
              's_4' => 0,
              's_5' => 0,
              's_6' => 0,
              's_7' => 0,
              's_8' => 0,
              's_9' => 0,
              'scheduled_downtime' => 'NO',
              'source' => '',
              'state' => 'HARD',
              'status' => 'OK',
              'status_msg' => 'status ok',
              'trap' => 1,
              'ts_0' => 1432875317,
              'ts_1' => 0,
              'ts_2' => 0,
              'ts_3' => 0,
              'ts_4' => 0,
              'ts_5' => 0,
              'ts_6' => 0,
              'ts_7' => 0,
              'ts_8' => 0,
              'ts_9' => 0
            },
            {
              'acknowledged' => 'N/A',
              'check_type' => 'ACTIVE',
              'current_attempt' => 1,
              'deleted' => 0,
              'dimensions' => {
                                'cluster' => 'cluster',
                                'service' => 'Prod-Deploy',
                                'host' => 'hostfoobar'
                              },
              'flapping' => 'N/A',
              'frequency' => 0,
              'hidden' => 0,
              'last_ack_time' => 0,
              'last_check_time' => 1432875229,
              'last_comment_time' => 0,
              'last_delete_time' => 1432875229,
              'last_downtime_time' => 0,
              'last_notif_time' => 0,
              'last_state_change' => 1432875094,
              'last_status_change' => 1432875094,
              'max_attempt' => 1,
              'msg_length' => 10,
              'notification_enabled' => 'ENABLED',
              'num_comments' => 0,
              'quality_metric' => 0,
              's_0' => 0,
              's_1' => 0,
              's_2' => 0,
              's_3' => 0,
              's_4' => 0,
              's_5' => 0,
              's_6' => 0,
              's_7' => 0,
              's_8' => 0,
              's_9' => 0,
              'scheduled_downtime' => 'NO',
              'source' => '',
              'state' => 'HARD',
              'status' => 'OK',
              'status_msg' => 'status ok',
              'trap' => 1,
              'ts_0' => 1432875229,
              'ts_1' => 1432875094,
              'ts_2' => 0,
              'ts_3' => 0,
              'ts_4' => 0,
              'ts_5' => 0,
              'ts_6' => 0,
              'ts_7' => 0,
              'ts_8' => 0,
              'ts_9' => 0
            },
            {
              'acknowledged' => 'N/A',
              'check_type' => 'ACTIVE',
              'current_attempt' => 1,
              'deleted' => 0,
              'dimensions' => {
                                'cluster' => 'cluster',
                                'query' => 'foobar',
                                'service' => 'foobar',
                                'host' => 'hostfoobar'
                              },
              'flapping' => 'N/A',
              'frequency' => 60,
              'hidden' => 0,
              'last_ack_time' => 1433949747,
              'last_check_time' => 1433949867,
              'last_comment_time' => 1421368592,
              'last_delete_time' => 1433949867,
              'last_downtime_time' => 1421376467,
              'last_notif_time' => 1427825899,
              'last_state_change' => 1407310478,
              'last_status_change' => 1433949867,
              'max_attempt' => 1,
              'msg_length' => 172,
              'notification_enabled' => 'ENABLED',
              'num_comments' => 8,
              'quality_metric' => 0,
              's_0' => 0,
              's_1' => 1,
              's_2' => 0,
              's_3' => 0,
              's_4' => 0,
              's_5' => 0,
              's_6' => 0,
              's_7' => 0,
              's_8' => 0,
              's_9' => 0,
              'scheduled_downtime' => 'NO',
              'source' => '',
              'state' => 'HARD',
              'status' => 'OK',
              'status_msg' => 'UNKNOWN.',
              'trap' => 0,
              'ts_0' => 1433949867,
              'ts_1' => 1433949747,
              'ts_2' => 1433949687,
              'ts_3' => 1433949627,
              'ts_4' => 1433949567,
              'ts_5' => 1433949507,
              'ts_6' => 1433949447,
              'ts_7' => 1433949387,
              'ts_8' => 1433949327,
              'ts_9' => 1433949267
            },
            {
              'acknowledged' => 'N/A',
              'check_type' => 'ACTIVE',
              'current_attempt' => 1,
              'deleted' => 0,
              'dimensions' => {
                                'cluster' => 'cluster',
                                'service' => 'Production_Deployment',
                                'host' => 'hostfoobar'
                              },
              'flapping' => 'N/A',
              'frequency' => 0,
              'hidden' => 0,
              'last_ack_time' => 0,
              'last_check_time' => 1432875270,
              'last_comment_time' => 0,
              'last_delete_time' => 0,
              'last_downtime_time' => 0,
              'last_notif_time' => 0,
              'last_state_change' => 1432875270,
              'last_status_change' => 1432875270,
              'max_attempt' => 1,
              'msg_length' => 10,
              'notification_enabled' => 'ENABLED',
              'num_comments' => 0,
              'quality_metric' => 0,
              's_0' => 0,
              's_1' => 0,
              's_2' => 0,
              's_3' => 0,
              's_4' => 0,
              's_5' => 0,
              's_6' => 0,
              's_7' => 0,
              's_8' => 0,
              's_9' => 0,
              'scheduled_downtime' => 'NO',
              'source' => '',
              'state' => 'HARD',
              'status' => 'OK',
              'status_msg' => 'status ok',
              'trap' => 1,
              'ts_0' => 1432875270,
              'ts_1' => 0,
              'ts_2' => 0,
              'ts_3' => 0,
              'ts_4' => 0,
              'ts_5' => 0,
              'ts_6' => 0,
              'ts_7' => 0,
              'ts_8' => 0,
              'ts_9' => 0
            }
          ]
        ];
```

Comment: There are many ways. What you are asking is too broad. You should tell what you have tried so far and what you are expecting.

Comment: The answer depends completely on what you want. What's wrong with the `for` loop that you have written?

Comment: I get the error below when trying to de-reference  the hash. Pseudo-hashes are deprecated at ./ymsclient.pl line 44.
Pseudo-hashes are deprecated at ./ymsclient.pl line 44.
Argument "N/A" isn't numeric in hash dereference at ./ymsclient.pl line 44.
Bad index while coercing array into hash at ./ymsclient.pl line 44.

Comment: I've updated my answer below with how to deal with your data structure now that we've finalized what it is (an array of arrays of hashes).

Answer (score 1):

Below is a script that shows how to iterate over a loop the Perl idiomatic way. It doesn't go deeper than a 3rd level, but it should be enough to give you some good ideas. In the while() loop, it shows how to dereference an inner hash as a whole and without needing the incrementor, and shows how to properly dereference and access individual items within the structure.

EDIT: We've found OP actually has an array of arrays of hashes. Code updated.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @aoh = (
            [
                {
                    1 => 'a',
                    2 => 'b',
                    3 => 'c',
                },
                {
                    'z' => 26,
                    'd' => {
                            100 => '3rd level',
                           },
                    'y' => 25,
                    'x' => 24,
                },
            ],
);

for my $element (@aoh){

    for my $level_2_element (@{ $element }){

        while  (my ($key, $value) = (each %{ $level_2_element })){
            if (ref($value) eq 'HASH'){
                while (my ($k, $v) = (each %{$value})){
                    print "$key: -- $k: $v\n";

                }
            }
            else {
                print "$key: $value\n";
            }
        }
    }
}

print "Element 0 0, key 1: $aoh[0]->[0]{1}\n";
print "Element 0 1, key x: $aoh[0]->[1]{x}\n";
```

Comment: I tried your solutions and I also had tried de referencing the way you suggested but both brings back the pseudo hash error Pseudo-hashes are deprecated at ./ymsclient.pl line 44.
Argument "ENABLED" isn't numeric in hash element at ./ymsclient.pl line 44.
Bad index while coercing array into hash at ./ymsclient.pl line 44.

Comment: Also here is the same issue recurring when i tried the code snippet in your comment Pseudo-hashes are deprecated at ./ymsclient.pl line 43.
Pseudo-hashes are deprecated at ./ymsclient.pl line 43.
Argument "N/A" isn't numeric in each at ./ymsclient.pl line 43.
Bad index while coercing array into hash at ./ymsclient.pl line 43.

Comment: Your latest edit also has the same issue,  I use perl, v5.8.6 

 Pseudo-hashes are deprecated at ./ymsclient.pl line 44.
Pseudo-hashes are deprecated at ./ymsclient.pl line 44.
Argument "N/A" isn't numeric in each at ./ymsclient.pl line 44.
Bad index while coercing array into hash at ./ymsclient.pl line 44.

Comment: That error means you are trying to access an array as a hash. Please post a `print Dumper \@results` immediately after receiving the data. Something isn't adding up.

Comment: Also, remove your loop with the iterators completely, and just try to `print "$results[0]->{'notification_enabled'}\n"` instead.

Comment: print Dumper \@results added to the post

Comment: ahh so what you've got is an array of arrays, which then contain hashes... give me  a minute and I'll fix my code

Comment: My code is updated to reflect your actual returned data (array of arrays of hashes)

Comment: It works like a charm!  I don't have the privileges enough to vote up this answer but much appreciated mate!

Comment: Awesome :) You can mark the question as correct though

Comment: I was able to individually access other elements using $result[0]->[0]{'last_check_time'}\n"; but how do I access anything under here ? 

'dimensions' => {
                                          'cluster' => '<cluster>',
                                          'service' => '<servicename>',
                                          'host' => 'hostfoobaar'
                                        },

Comment: `$result[0]->[0]{'dimensions'}{'cluster'}` or `my $href = $result[0]->[0]{'dimensions'};` then `$href->{'cluster'}` and `for my $k in (%$href){ print "$href->{$k}\n"; }`